# Nioh mouse setting

Tags: mouse, nioh

i'm playing Nioh just with mouse and keyboard but i cant change mouse 
targeting switch or even disable it then it so annoying with fight multi target
please help

Comment: no it doesn't my answer

Comment: Why doesn't it? Can you be more constructive with your feedback?